# Uploading file is successful on the server computer but it fails on other computers on the network

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Blazor server app in my project. I'm using syncfusion upload component for Blazor. I use the following code to upload file to the server:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFilledPmFile(IList<IFormFile> UploadFile, string pmSchedualId, int userId)
    {
        try
        {
            var selectedPmSchedual = await _sqliteContext.PmScheduals.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PmSchedualId == pmSchedualId);

            if (selectedPmSchedual != null)
            {
                //Check for previous filename
                if (selectedPmSchedual.UploadedFileName != null)
                {
                    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Data\PmScheduals\UploadedByUsers", selectedPmSchedual.UploadedFileName);
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                    }
                }
                //FileUpload
                foreach (var file in UploadFile)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    var newFileName = string.Concat(Guid.NewGuid(), fileExtension);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Data\PmScheduals\UploadedByUsers", newFileName);

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }

                    selectedPmSchedual.UploadFileDate = DateTime.Now;
                    selectedPmSchedual.UploadedFileName = newFileName;
                    selectedPmSchedual.UploaderUserRef = userId;

                    _sqliteContext.Update(selectedPmSchedual);
                    await _sqliteContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                    var newNotification = new Notification
                    {
                        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                        NotificationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    };

                    var userNotification = new UserNotification 
                    { 
                        IsSeen = false,
                        NotificationRef = newNotification.NotificationId,
                        UserRef = 1
                    };

                    await _sqliteContext.Notifications.AddAsync(newNotification);
                    await _sqliteContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    await _sqliteContext.UserNotifications.AddAsync(userNotification);
                    await _sqliteContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                }

                return Ok();
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

When I host my app using IIS on the server, I can upload file on server computer but on other computers connected to this server, uploading fails.
How can I fix it?

Comment: In IIS, I cannot debug where the error happens.